# Keep only most recent n lines of output in file

Tags: shell-script, logs, io-redirection

I am running a program on a computing cluster which periodically crashes due to a segmentation fault, so I would like to retain the verbose debugging output to diagnose why. However, the program could potentially run for multiple hours without crashing, so if I redirect the entire output to a file using `srun my-program-binary > output.log 2>&1`, the result is a logfile so large that it exceeds my disk quota on the cluster. Since I only need the most recent n lines of output (say, around 1000), I was wondering if there was a way to keep a running buffer of output and retain only the most recent portion at a given time for future reference.

I am limited in what I can install on the cluster, so I would need a solution that doesn't require non-standard packages. [This solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310860/how-do-you-keep-only-the-last-n-lines-of-a-log-file) does not work for my situation since I cannot wait until the file is created before retaining only the last portion, I need to keep a running buffer that never exceeds a certain length/memory size. Does anyone know of a way to do something like this?

Comment: This looks like. Reinventing logging again. More specifically reinventing log rotation: This is what log rotation is for. If it does not do exactly what you want, then try a different log rotation tool.

Comment: My understanding is that this type of solution would not work since replacing the file while output is still being redirected to it will not cause output to be redirected to the new file, but rather will be lost.

Comment: It depends how it is done: The logger would have to re-open the file for each short message. But here again we are starting to reinvent logging again. Use what already exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `bash`, `wc` and `sed`, you can use a little script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
nlines=$2

while read line ; do
    echo "$line" >> $file
    read clines _ <<< $(wc -l $file)
    if [[ clines -gt nlines ]] ; then
        n=$(( clines - nlines ))
        sed -i -e 1,${n}d $file
    fi
done
```

Use it with a pipe: `srun my-program-binary 2>&1 | a_little_script output.log 1000`

The script does

- read every line from the output of `my-program-binary` and echo it to output.log
- get the current number of lines in output.log
- remove the first n lines exceeding `nlines`

This way you always have the last n lines of output in your log file. It uses very little memory and CPU.

Answer (score 1):

If the 1000 (or so) lines can fit in memory, one way would be to buffer
the lines in memory until something happens:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# keepn - keep N lines of input in memory, and print them at exit
$0 = 'keepn';    # pkill(1) target (some OS do not honor this)
my $keep = shift // 1000;
my $okay = 1;
$SIG{$_} = sub { $okay = 0 } for qw(HUP INT PIPE TERM USR1);

my @buf;
while ( $okay and defined( my $line = readline ) ) {
    push @buf, $line;
    my $over = @buf - $keep;
    if ( $over > 0 ) { splice @buf, 0, $over }
}
END { print for @buf }
```

A downside here is that if the `keepn` process is killed, then so are
the buffered log lines. The signal handling might help prevent some
of those edge cases. Periodic syncs of the `@buf` to disk would
increase I/O but better ensure that there are some log lines, but
hopefully `keepn` is not unreliable or a target for an out of control
out-of-memory killer.

```
srun my-program-binary 2>&1 | keepn 1000 > output
```

### Send the logs somewhere else

Another option would be to pipe to `logger(1)` and let a syslog daemon
handle where the output needs to go, but that would require control of a
syslog daemon or logging framework. This could mean that the logs might
be accumulated elsewhere, where you might have a larger disk quota to
burn through. But it would be a lot more complicated to setup. A TCP
socket or web API could also be used to send the log output elsewhere,
for better or worse.

### tmux

Terminal multiplexer such as `tmux` offer limited scrollback; one
would simple run the job under `tmux` then use the buffer scrollback
to see what the last few lines of the log were, up to the
`history-limit` setting:

```
set-option -g history-limit 1000
```